# Reporting Services 2005 IE data anomaly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have a SSRS 05 report that works perfect in most instances.
I have a user that using IE can see data in the report except when querying a specific month.

When he logs in to the application on another machine, or through Chrome, it pulls data correctly.

He has upgraded to IE10 and still has this issue. (on other computers with IE10 his account works fine.)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time and assistance!

Comment: Only asking because you didn't specifically mention this - does the report work correctly for other users in IE on that computer (the one which does not work for him)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I should have mentioned that we are seeing the same results with multiple accounts.

Again, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Could you run an SQL Profiler trace to see what SQL is actually being run when the report fails? I'm supposing that locale settings on the machine will cause it to send through incorrect dates or something.